# Ability to Bulk Update List views sharing settings?

Tags: community, list-view

We are installing a new Community now, and like many others, we find that all list views are set to: All Users
But we want to hide them all from External users.

There is an idea on that: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhFPUAZ/ability-to-bulk-update-list-view-sharing-settings
But ain't looking too bright..

Is there a way to do this via meta data? REST ? Any wizard out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to note:

1. [ListView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm) is stored within Custom Object.

> List views are stored within a CustomObject component. The component can represent a custom object or a standard object, such as an account.

2. [SharedTo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sharedto.htm) within ListView is what you're looking to change - but, it's not included in public list views' metadata

> SharedTo is included in the metadata for shared and private list views. SharedTo isn’t in the metadata for public list views.

3. If you already have source control, then you already have all your objects - otherwise, you'll have to make sure to pull all objects (or *whichever* you're interested in). For standard objects, this means you'll have to explicitly call them out `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject: Account` as you'll only get custom objects if you just do `sfdx force:source:reterieve -m CustomObject`. If you're starting from scratch, [OrgBrowser](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/org-browser) would allow you to click on `Retrieve Source from Org` on `Custom Objects` and get all standard/custom objects.
4. Instead of assuming all lists view are public, it'd be worth doing a search all to see if you do find any references to `<sharedTo>` to confirm they're all public. If you do find references, you could note those file names & look to exclude those files from your search & replace below.

Now, in your project in VS Code, you can just do a find and replace across all your files. When you do search all (`CTRL + F`), make sure to click the toggle button next to the search input.

[image]

In this scenario, *assuming all list views are public* as you note, you could do the following:

Search:

`</ListView>`

Replace:

```
    <sharedTo>allInternalUsers</sharedTo>
</ListView>
```

Once you've updated all the files, you can just right-click on the `objects` folder and select "Deploy Source to Org" (or run sfdx command).